# Unable to share a folder through Azure Dev Ops agent

Tags: permissions, active-directory, azure-devops

I have a windows agent running on Azure Dev Ops.

i want it to share a folder. I create the folder and execute the following commands:

```
 net share FolderName=FoldeRPath
```

Then I commented out the folder creation code (to isolate the error). I changed the permission on that folder and gave the devops agent user all the permission to that folder.

Added the devops agent as administrator. Still running into the following issue while trying to share the folder:

```
 System error 5 has occurred.
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: What is the goal of this share? Why are you creating it?

Comment: My code creates some logs, which should be accessible from outside the agents

Comment: Publish the logs as a build artifact.

Comment: Sure. But still curious as to why I cannot share a folder. I tried simple 'net share' to print the list of shared folders and that also says permission denied